# Is node js is middleware?

Tags: node.js

When I have started learning nodeJs , I was consider this as a server side back end language . But then I came to know from a senior developer that NodeJs is not back end , it is middle ware .

I don't find any specific article for this point .. can anyone clear this . Is it only middle ware , or can be use as middle ware language with a server side language ?

Comment: Node is not a back end or a middleware -- it's a runtime environment for Javascript that can be used to write more or less whatever you'd like... including server back-ends and middleware.

Comment: Thanx @ChristopherRonning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read this https://nodejs.org/en

indeed node.js behave like back-end and can replace php, asp.net.
there are a lot of supported framework to do mvc application on node.js, e.g., express, koa

Answer (score 0):

It supported by  the google V8 engine, compile to c++, making js more efficiency and faster. So it can do lots things not only server side or middleware.

Because the rapid development, lots company use it as middleware, then the front-end can write both side code.